# How execute commands after loading of checkout?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need execute `jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` after checkout shipping (billing) form loaded (step 1).

What I need to do?

Comment: Is widget element (`.selectpicker`) added by your module?

Comment: @MaxStsepantsevich no, my theme. Problem is find an event after creation of the shipping form.